# android ndk java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to get an android app running. It should contain can-android communication.
my project is called CANAndroid. the path is com.example.canandroid .
That for i'm currently using this java file:
package com.example.canandroid;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public native void jinit(int type, int port, int irq);
public native void jreceive();


EditText et;
Button b1;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v("BLA","Hier wird die App gestartet");
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);

    b1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            jreceive();
                            //or jinit(0,0,0);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

static{
    System.loadLibrary("receive_test");


}
```

}

My receivetest.c-file looks like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_CANAndroid_MainActivity_jinit(JNIEnv *env,jint  nType, jint dwPort, jint wIrq){
 //do sth
}



JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_CANAndroid_MainActivity_jreceive(){
//do sth
}
```

My receivetest.h looks like this:
    #include

```
#ifndef _Included_com_example_CANAndroid_MainActivity
#define _Included_com_example_CANAndroid_MainActivity
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_CANAndroid_MainActivity_jinit
(JNIEnv *,jint, jint, jint);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_CANAndroid_MainActivity_jreceive();



 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
 #endif
```

I'm compiling with the ndk-toolchain. so my android.mk looks like this

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE :=receive_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILE := receivetest.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The app starts, but as soon as i press the buttong i get this error message:

```
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jinit
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.example.canandroid.MainActivity.jinit(Native Method)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.example.canandroid.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 00:18:09.800: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've searched trough several threats on stackoverflow. All of them contain spelling errors of the native methods. I can't find any of these in my programm, so maybe someone can see my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is thrown when an attempt is made to invoke a native for which an implementation could not be found. 
you should have to check "receive_test" is in your class path & is correctly set. 
copying "receive_test" in Android libs directory may solves your problem.

Comment: my receivetest.h and receivetest.h are in my /jni folder of my android project. the receive_test.so is in the /libs and /obj as it gets created by the ndk-build toolchain. since im new to the "path" settings, i dont really understand what u mean by "is in your class path". and where can i find andoird libs, arent ndk libs usually allways saved in the /libs folder of the project ?

Comment: I've allready found an error myself. my void methodes didnt contain enough parameter so i had to  rename my package and use javah to get the correct receivetest.h. now that i've done that i got the following receivetest.h 

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_name_canandroid_MainActivity_jinit
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint, jint);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_name_canandroid_MainActivity_jreceive
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

this error is fixed, still i have the same error message: UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: I found the error. in my android.mk the line LOCAL_SRC_FILE := receivetest.c needs to be LOCAL_SRC_FILES := receivetest.c . Because of that error the android toolchain didnt even find the receivetest.c